# How to get consistency in neural network and eliminate possibility of NaN values?

Tags: regression, time-series, lstm, keras

I'm using a neural network(Keras,LSTM) for time series regression. Whenever I run the network, I get different outputs for the prediction. This is presumably due to the randomised weight initialization. Sometimes the loss becomes NaN.

Is setting the seed to a certain value okay? I thought the models were supposed to converge to around the same values regardless of the seed value?

How can I remove the NaN loss that I get sometimes?

Comment: What kind of loss function are you using? Is it possible that in some iterations you're trying to take the `log` of someting that might become negative or divide by something that might become 0 (instant NaN) or very small (possible buffer overflow)?

Comment: Can you please describe the layers you are using? It is often the case that one should reduce batch or layer size to eliminate this issue, but it is not possible to say without knowing what layers you are using.

Comment: @hdkrgr I'm using adam optimizer with MSE loss.

Comment: @MichaelGrogan It's the CNNLSTM as described here https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/. However I'm using more layers of Dense after the LSTM along with dropout. I'm also using more neurons in LSTM and filters in Convolution layer (256 each.) I'll try reducing layer size,though.

Comment: @Chalant I think that would be a good first step, and then see are you still getting NaNs.

Comment: @MichaelGrogan That only reduced the chances of getting NaN, but didn't eliminate it, so I used gradient clipping. Haven't got any NaN's since then. But I still wonder whether gradient clipping is the correct thing to do because it kinda seems like 'cheating'

Comment: @Chalant Hard to say without seeing your data up close. From what I can gather, gradient clipping can be helpful in the presence of exponential gradients which result in the NaN values you are finding, you might find this thread more informative on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498127/how-to-apply-gradient-clipping-in-tensorflow

Comment: As a side note - setting your seed to some arbitrary constant value is a good thing, it makes your results reproducible. Setting it to the best value is a different thing, and is considered bad practice, as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Most NANs in Keras are linked to either NANs in inputs or too high of a learning rate. Seeing that you don't always get NAN loss I would decrease the learning rate and see if it helps (probably will also help with convergence).

Precision errors, especially when using float16, are also possible but they are more common with log-loss rather than MSE and you didn't mention that you use float16 (default is 32) so I wouldn't think it is an issue here